# SQL get to C# with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection, sqldatareader

I have a problem. I want to get data from my SQL Server database. When the code is running, the first row isn't getting added to my arraylist. All other rows get added successfully. In SQL Server, the query works fine, but in VS, it doesn't work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog=TripData;Integrated Security=SSPI");
    baglanti.Open();

    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand();
    komut.CommandText = "select top 50 trip_ID from Sayfa1$";
    komut.Connection = baglanti;

    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataReader oku = komut.ExecuteReader();

    while (oku.Read())
    {
        foreach (var item in oku)
        {
            gecici.Add(oku["trip_ID"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need foreach loop here. Just remove it and it should work fine

Comment: I would remove that ExecuteNonQuery() on the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to iterate over the reader in two different ways - using both a `foreach` loop *and* using `while (reader.Read())`. You should do one or the other - I've personally seen more code using `while (reader.Read())` than the `foreach` approach.

Additionally I'd suggest using `using` statements for the disposable objects in your code - and not calling `ExecuteNonQuery` first. (It's not clear why you're doing that at all). So you could write:

```
// Note that this looks like a mixture of UI and non-UI code; consider separating
// them for greater code reuse, separation of concerns etc.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Declare connectionString elsewhere, or have a common method to open the connection.
    // You're likely to need that in multiple places.
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("select top 50 trip_ID from Sayfa1$", connection))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {    
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    gecici.Add(oku["trip_ID"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Also if you're *really* using `ArrayList` as your post suggests, I'd definitely urge you to start using the generic collections, e.g. `List<string>` in this case.)